# Unit testing/code coverage when dependency injection isn't possible

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, code-coverage

This problem is best explained with code, so lets say you have a Javascript file called `myFancyLibrary.js` that looks like this:

```
var curl = require("node-curl");
var MyApiRequester = require("./MyApiRequester");

module.exports = {
    wasCalled: false,
    makeRequest: function(){
        this.wasCalled = true;
        var requester = new MyApiRequester( curl );
        requester.send();
    }
};
```

As you can see, curl is passed as a parameter so `MyApiRequester`'s unit tests can use a mock/stub and not actually make cURL requests.

My question is how could you unit test `makeRequest()` without making a curl request?

I realize that you could just create a wrapper for `myFancyLibrary.js` and pass `MyApiRequester` in as a parameter, but then the wrapper will just have the same problem.

The highest level module will inevitably be unable to receive dependency injected objects since there is nowhere to receive them from. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to not send a request in the makeRequest() function, you'd have to modify that function to take a Requester interface so you can mock it out in the test.  Given the fact that this function is so small, you might be looking at diminishing returns, and would be better off covering this case with a functional test.